# I got multiple rsync during a sync against webdav

Tags: rsync, webdav, owncloud

I have trouble to sync a folder with a mounted webdav (provided by owncloud) on a client.

First I mounted the webdav folder to /company/webdav, this is fine and can browse this directory.

```
mount -t davfs https://webdav.company.com/remote.php/webdav /company/webdav
```

After this I run this command to make a sync of the video folder to my local raspberry

```
rsync -av --delete-after --progress --partial --stats /company/webdav/Video/ /companylocal/video
```

It seems it works with small files (<50MB), if I do it with larger files in /companylocal/video I can see duplicate partical files.

> root@pi:/companylocal/video# ls -al total 1270300 drwxr-xr-x 2 root
>   root      4096 Dec  6 16:03 . drwxr-xr-x 9 root root      4096 Dec  6
>   15:45 ..
>   -rw------- 1 root root 159383552 Dec  6 16:03 .Backstage_+_FWB_Show.mp4.cL5tVu
>   -rw------- 1 root root 595591168 Dec  6 15:54 .Backstage_+_FWB_Show.mp4.hfti8J
>   -rw------- 1 root root 159383552 Dec  6 16:03 .Backstage_+_FWB_Show.mp4.JB0tfu
>   -rw------- 1 root root 159383552 Dec  6 16:03 .Backstage_+_FWB_Show.mp4.odvZEr
>   -rw------- 1 root root 159383552 Dec  6 16:03 .Backstage_+_FWB_Show.mp4.pM5wCu
>   -rw------- 1 root root  67633152 Dec  6 16:03 .Backstage_+_FWB_Show.mp4.WRljSA

Also there is only one file which has to be synced, but rsync is getting much more processes

```
root@pi:/companylocal/video# top 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  975 davfs2    20   0   41524   4916   4088 D   2.6  0.5   2:24.78 mount.davfs
  985 root      20   0    5064   1532   1040 S   2.3  0.2   0:04.68 rsync
 1320 root      20   0    5064   1568   1072 S   2.3  0.2   0:04.71 rsync
 1322 root      20   0    5064   1540   1040 S   2.3  0.2   0:04.63 rsync
 1352 root      20   0    5064   1540   1044 S   2.3  0.2   0:04.09 rsync
  977 root      20   0    5092   2616   2112 D   2.0  0.3   0:03.70 rsync
 1314 root      20   0    5092   2608   2108 D   2.0  0.3   0:03.69 rsync
 1349 root      20   0    5092   2596   2092 S   2.0  0.3   0:03.37 rsync
 1423 root      20   0    5092   2476   2036 S   2.0  0.3   0:00.52 rsync
 1425 root      20   0    5064   1616   1132 S   2.0  0.2   0:00.46 rsync
```

I didn't understand why this could happen.

The problem is: If rsync try to sync parallel the same file, the bandwithusage is high, and also the storage will be full after some minutes. The file has only 2GB and 10 files x 2 GB = 20GB will kill my discspace.

Is it an problem of combination (large file via owncloud-webdav) and rsync ?
Should I use native webdav via Apache ? Or is there only a mistake in my rsync command ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `rsync` is getting file-chunks from your dav-mounted FS but it's missing the last re-assembly step other clients would do once downloaded (since being a *general-purppose* sync engine makes it unaware of the server particulars). Appending manually all those chunks in order should result on the original file.

But that's a crazy amount of manual work. I'd suggest you to use [`owncloudcmd`](https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/2.1/advancedusage.html#owncloud-command-line-client) instead, since it's aware of the server capabilities and conceived to do the trick.

Also, in order to limit how much bandwidht `rsync` uses, you can flip the `--bwlimit=<kb/second>` argument to control it doesn't eat all your network speed. The equivalent flags for `owncloudcmd` are available in the upcoming 2.4 version: https://github.com/owncloud/client/pull/5707